# Alert on partition growth

Tags: file-system, bash, linux

I have a script that alerts me via email when a partition grows past a defined threshold in one hour. My script is run from cron hourly. Everything seems fine for 99% of the time, but occasionally I get an email from my script stating that growth in the past hour is something like ".08%", well below my current threshold of 0.75%. Is something wrong with my logic?

```
#Drive to monitor
monDrive=/opt
#Enter a number .01-100. i.e 50 = 50%, and 0.5 = 1/2 of a percent.
percentThreshold=0.75
#Email address to send alerts to
emailAlert=alerts@domain.com


##Do not modify anything below this point
prevReading=/root/diskcheckreading.txt



checkDiskUse() {
        df "$monDrive" | awk 'END{printf "%0.2f",$2/$1*100; exit}'
}

checkDiskFree() {
        df "$monDrive" | awk 'END{printf "%0.2f",$3/1048576; exit}'
}

#Check if file exists with previous reading
[ -f $prevReading ] && prev=$(cat $prevReading) || { checkDiskUse > $prevReading; exit; }

#Validate file content
printf "%0.2f" "$prev" > /dev/null || exit

#Get current percentage used of monitored drive
current=$(checkDiskUse)

#Get current free capacity of monitored drive
diskFree=$(checkDiskFree)

#Calculate the difference
results=$(bc -l <<< $current-$prev )
#Check if the difference exceeds the threshold
if  [[ $results > $percentThreshold ]]
         then printf "\"$monDrive\" has grown $results%% in the past hour.     Remaining capacity on $monDrive is $diskFree GB.\n\n$(hostname):$(pwd)/$(basename $0)" | mail -s "Disk Alert - $(hostname):$monDrive" $emailAlert
fi

#log current reading for next check
echo $current > $prevReading
```

Comment: An observation I have just made is that if there is disk space freed up, then the alert will trigger with a negative number. If `$results` is greater than `$percentThreshold` it should trigger, but `$results` is a negative number and is less than the threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything seems fine for 99% of the time, but occasionally I get an
>   email from my script stating that growth in the past hour is something
>   like ".08%", well below my current threshold of 0.75%. Is something
>   wrong with my logic?

When the tools seem to defy your logic, play with simple examples.

The code that generates the message with ".08%" is this, roughly:

> ```
> printf "\"$monDrive\" has grown $results%% in the past hour. | mail ...
> ```

where the `$results` variable comes from:

> ```
> results=$(bc -l <<< $current-$prev )
> ```

and the threshold is checked with:

> ```
> if  [[ $results > $percentThreshold ]]
> ```

Now let's play a little:

```
$ [[ 0.08 > 0.75 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
$ [[ .08 > 0.75 ]] && echo true || echo false
true
```

A-ha! Apparently, 0.08 is smaller than 0.75, as expected but .08, with the leading zero omitted, is not smaller than 0.75, at least in Bash.

But why do you have .08 instead of 0.08 in the first place?
Let's play a bit more:

```
$ bc -l <<< 2.81-0.79
2.02
$ bc -l <<< 0.81-0.79
.02
$ bc -l <<< 0-0.79
-.79
```

Ah. So when the result is below 1, apparently, `bc` drops the leading zero.

So how to fix this? It seems there's no obvious way to [prevent `bc` from dropping the leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero). But as you're already doing many calculations using `awk`, you can move this calculation there too:

```
results=$(awk '{print $1 - $2}' <<< "$current $prev")
```

Note the space between `$current` and `$prev`, 
so that they can be used as `$1` and `$2` in `awk`.

#### Code review

> ```
>    df "$monDrive" | awk 'END{printf "%0.2f",$2/$1*100; exit}'
> ```

In the `END` block of `awk` you don't need to `exit`,
as the command will exit anyway.
I also recommend to add more spaces to make the expression easier to read:

```
    df "$monDrive" | awk 'END { printf "%0.2f", $2 / $1 * 100 }'
```

---

This seems completely pointless, you can delete it:

> ```
> #Validate file content
> printf "%0.2f" "$prev" > /dev/null || exit
> ```

Comment: Great explanation Janos, thank you! Now the only issue is that if I free up a bunch of space, then the alert triggers again, but with a negative number. When doing a Bash comparison, can it not handle negatives? In the most recent example, `[[ -0.93 > 0.75 ]]` is showing true.

Comment: Are you sure about that? `[[ -0.93 > 0.75 ]] && echo true || echo false` correctly gives me `false`

Comment: I think I am losing my mind. Take a look at this   `
[root@server ~]# [[ 2 > 1 ]] && echo true || echo false
**true**  
[root@server ~]# [[ 1 > 2 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
[root@server ~]# [[ 10 > 2 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
[root@server ~]# [[ -0.93 > 0.75 ]] && echo true || echo false
true`

Comment: It looks like [[ ]] compares strings, and that is why my results are skewed. I should be using (( )), but then any decimal comparison fails as Bash can't handle floating point. I switched to KSH, and all is good.